# How to Create Unique user code custom string in php?

Tags: php, mysql

In my database I have a column code. Its value JOB10001,JOB10002,JOB10003 like increment. how to use that column unique. currently i get the last row column then increment that value then Insert to the table. In rare case scenario two row inserted with same code value. when on same time is same second

Comment: You need [database transactions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_transaction).

Answer (score 0):

I guess you mean you have a column named `code`. And each row has a unique value like `JOB10001`, `JOB10002` and so on.
To make it unique (and let the RDBMS enforce it) you can define this column as `unique`.
In your DDL it is defined like this:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
    code CHAR(8) NOT NULL,
    another_row INT,
    UNIQUE(code)
);
```

The database will now reject any new rows where the value of code matches an already existing row. Note, that depending on your collation an input of `job10001` may be considered equal to `JOB10001`.

If your table already exists and you want to add the unique constraint, you can do it with one of these statements.

```
ALTER TABLE foo
ADD CONSTRAINT UC_code UNIQUE (code);
```

or if you don't want to use a named constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE foo
ADD UNIQUE (code);
```

Last thing: I don't know your use case, but it seems like the `JOB` part will be present in every row of this table, so you might want to add it in application code and use a "normal" `auto_increment` column and set the autoincrement counter to 10000 with `ALTER TABLE foo AUTO_INCREMENT=10000` so it will start to count from 10000 onwards.

Answer (score 0):

You may simply use a column `auto_increment` and `trigger` to make sure its unique.

Let the column is `ID` which has initial value=10001. now write a trigger after insert into table:

```
FOR EACH ROW 
 BEGIN
   code = CONCAT('JOB',new.ID) ;
 .......
 END //
```